# P-channel logic-level MOSFET that turns on properly when driven by an ESP32 (working from 3.0 V to 3.6 V)

Tags: mosfet, logic-level

I'm reading the specs of the ESP32 and I'm trying to find a P-channel MOSFET that I can drive with the GPIO pins.

The specs say that ESP32 works from 3.0 to 3.6 V. Its logical zero is at most 0.1 VDD and the logical one is at least 0.8 VDD. That means that (at 3.6 V) 0.8*3.6 V = 2.88 V is the lowest possible logical one of the GPIO pins.

I found that AO3401 has a -0.7 to -1.3 V gate threshold voltage. That means that for a logical 1 at a VDD of 3.0 V (same as the ESP32) it starts to switch from 2.3 V. At 3.6 V it starts at 2.9 V.

The problem is that if the ESP32 is driven by 3.6 V it might output 2.88 V for a logical one and that the AO3401 will already begin to switch (from 2.9 V already will be partially switched).

I have looked around the web, in forums, shops for parts, but was unable to find other suitable MOSFET. Ideally one that switches from around -1 V to around -2 V would be nice, but I have not found one. In this case at 3.6 V it will start to switch from 2.6 V (that is lower than 2.88 V). The N-channel IRLZ44N has exactly that: 1 V to 2 V, but its N-channel.

Is there such a MOSFET? Or should this 0.02 V difference not be considered a problem in practice?

Comment: For starters, I think you've misunderstood the meaning of *gate threshold voltage*. The gate threshold voltage is where the MOSFET starts to conduct at all. So the -0.7 to -1.3V range is for where it **starts** to conduct (typically where it can conduct a few hundred µA). It is not "fully switched on" at -1.3V, but it is guaranteed to have reached the threshold voltage where it starts to conduct at all. For it to be "fully switched on", you need higher Vgs. Datasheets typically has a graph for `Vgs` vs. `Id`, or `Vgs` vs. `Rds(on)`, take a look at that.

Comment: I'm sorry, its a new field for me. But that still does not change the fact that it might start to conduct at -0.7. I have edited the question.

Comment: Please specify your load voltage and current.

Comment: The output voltages you are referencing are with a non-zero load. Lightly loaded, CMOS outputs drive near the rail. Please post your circuit so there are no mis-understandings.

Comment: I have not have a particular schema. But for example, it could be another ESP32. As I understand my concern is valid. At certain conditions AO3401 can start conducting even that the ESP32 outputs HIGH by its specs.

Answer (score 3):

Let's not mix up some important concepts. The 0.8V logical one is the input voltage. This basically means that any voltage above 0.8V is seen as a logical one, but means nothing for an output logic one. For any modern microcontroller, when you set a pin to output logical one, it will output Vcc with a very slight, negligible drop. So if Vcc is 3.6V, you will apply that voltage on the gate.

When selecting a mosfet, Vgs(th) is misleading. It's only when the mosfet "starts to wake up". You need to find a mosfet with a typical resistance rating for your voltage. For example, let's take "PMV27UPER". From its [datasheet](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PMV27UPE.pdf), we see the following:

[image: MOSFET datasheet]

As you can see, Vgs(th) is rated at a maximum of -0.95V, but at that voltage it will only pass 250 microamps! However, go down to Rds(on) and you will find that it is rated for 3 voltages. 4.5V is higher than what the ESP can do, so you can take the next value of 2.5V

This part tells you that at 2.5V or higher, it will have a maximum drain to source resistance of 45 mohm.

It's not hard to search for this. When you go to https://www.digikey.com, you can find the following fields. Just select all parts that have a "Max Rds On" which is above Vcc. Here, I assumed Vcc can go as low as 3.0V, then added 0.2V as a buffer. Now all the parts you find can be turned on by the ESP, what remains then is wether the mosfet can pass the current, withstand the voltage, etc.
[image: Digikey parametric search]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'm actually trying to search by the minimum threshold voltage, to guarantie that the P-channel MOSFET does not conduct for logical one. If the specification states 0.8VDD I guess there is a reason for that. Maybe I can just pull the gate high with a resistor to ensure that its more closer to VDD.

Comment: @verbessern - There is another reason for a gate pull-up resistor. Without it, the signal will be indeterminate until the MCU boots and programs the GPIO.

Comment: @verbessern When you output "one" from a microcontroller, you will get Vcc. When you output "zero", you will get Vss (GND). That means that you need a pmos that fully turns on at Vgs = Vcc (so 3.3V, which happens when you give the gate 0V and the source 3.3V, and if the PMOS has 3.3V on its source, you can turn it off by outputting a logic high so that Vgs is 3.3-3.3=0V

Answer (score 2):

If you do not load the output to ground, the output will be very close to the rail. There is no problem with this circuit (assuming the GPIO power domain is 3.3V):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2ewAa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The Espressif datasheet specifies a minimum Voh of 0.8Vdd with a 20mA load. That means with a load < 2mA the minimum Voh will be better than 0.98Vdd (so |Vgs| will be less than 68mV). Since you presumably have no resistor to ground the Voh may be even closer to Vdd (when you get down to mV there may be voltage drops across the PCB and internally in the chip so it's hard to predict).

You might want to add a small series resistor to the gate to limit the peak current (and the resulting glitch on the Vcc line) but it's not important to the drive voltage consideration.